# How to check data exist to in order to render a result?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code here : XXXXX sorry code no longer available will include soon.

What I would like to happen is when I click a button the 'index' of each object is passed like this:

`const priceShown = product[evenIndex].price;`

But when the pages loads I get an error saying `price` is undefined :(

I know its something to do with the data not existing yet (I have little knowledge as to why this is a thing so if you could also explain this would be a great bonus too!) .

To check if the data is there before `priceShown` I wrote this:

```
if (evenIndex !== null) {
  return evenIndex;
} else {
   console.log('no data');
};
```

This returns the `no data` part of the statement always as you can't pass an index (`evenIndex`) unless you click on a button, so `price` will always be undefined? Unless its undefined for another reason of which I do not know.

Any Help?

Comment: Please put all the code in the question instead of on an off-site resource. External links can become invalid over time, making the question less useful to future visitors.

Comment: Oh cool hmm not sure how to do that haven't been using stackoverflow for too long will play about and add it thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if `product[evenIndex]` is set first, and then take out the `price` if it is. This way no price will be rendered until an index has been selected.

```
const priceShown = product[evenIndex] && product[evenIndex].price;
```

Comment: Ohh that was easy, Thanks! Thought it would be more code than that haha. Awesome

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify whether `evenIndex` even exists before trying to access the `product` array. You can even get rid of evenIndex as it serves no use in your example.

```
const priceShown =
  this.state.evenSelected == null
    ? "No data"
    : product[this.state.evenSelected].price;
```

Here's an updated version of the code you linked:
[https://codesandbox.io/s/kmw7npp7z5](http://CodeSandbox)